# How can I modify the DevOps State Graph?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

How can I modify the State Graph?

[image]

I know where to modify the name of the states. I also found where I can create new states. Now I would like to change the explanation given between each state. Where can I do that? I would like to change the "Acceptance tests pass" by something else.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason field of state changes is not possible to modify in Azure DevOps Services:

1. [Ability to customize WIT State Reason in Inheritance Process Model](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ability-to-customize-wit-state-reason-in-inheritan/365937)
2. [How to hide or edit the reason field in Azure DevOps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/how-to-hide-or-edit-the-reason-field-in-azure-devops/)